# Strictly Convex Smoothing of a function defined on an affine manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, convexity, affine-geometry

A function defined on an interval is *strongly convex* if it has positive definite second derivative. A function on an affine manifold is *strongly convex*
if its restriction to each line is. An *affine manifold* is given by charts whose transitions functions are affine. I have proved the following, but would be grateful if someone could provide a reference.

Suppose $M$ is a connected affine manifold and $f:M\longrightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is  a convex function, which  is strictly convex at some point. Given $\epsilon>0$ there is  $g:M\longrightarrow {\mathbb R},$ which is smooth, strongly convex and satisfies $|f-g|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Daryl: Maybe you should clarify what you mean by an affine manifold: Some people assume that this is just a manifold equipped with an affine connection, other's assume that the connection is flat.